# dividir un array por indices numericos

Tags: javascript

deseo que los indices pares 2,4,6 que hacen referencia a paises asiaticos se guarden en su respectivo array, y el resto en el otro array

```
mix = ['nulla' , 'italia', 'cina', 'germany', 'india', 'france', 'japan']  
europa = []
asia = []
```

con la siguiente operacion recibo solo un error undefined

```
mix.map(function(indice){ if(indice % 2 == 0) {asia.push(indice)}}) // undefined
```

con mi anterior codigo no tenia nigun problema

```
 numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
numbers.map(function(x){if(x % 2 == 0) {pares.push(x)}})

/*
undefined
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10] ] */

numbers.map(function(x){if(x % 2 == 1) {dispares.push(x)}}) // undefined [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```

aunque no entendia porque me devolvie undefined

Comment: No está claro cómo estas usando la función map. Agrega un [mcve].

Comment: a lo mejor debe ser porque lo usaba desde la consola, los elementos se agregaban con el ciclo for, todo desde la consola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una forma de ver `arr.map(a,b)` es considerar que el primer argumento `a` es el elemento de la matriz `arr`, el índice, `b`, sería el segundo argumento.

En [Array.protoype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map) se hablan de tres argumentos, el elemento y el índice y lo matriz en el ejemplo incluido arriba  `a`, `b` y `arr` respectivamente.

Ejemplo:

```js
var mix = ['nulla' , 'italia', 'cina', 'germany', 'india', 'france', 'japan']  
var asia =[];
mix.map(function(elemento,indice){
  if (indice % 2 == 0) asia.push(elemento);
});
document.write(asia);
```

Con respecto a

```
mix = ['nulla' , 'italia', 'cina', 'germany', 'india', 'france', 'japan'];
mix.map(function(indice){ if(indice % 2 == 0) {asia.push(indice)}})
```

Devuelve `undefined` para cada uno de los elementos de la matriz, porque el primer argumento toma el un elemento del a matriz en cada iteración, por ejemplo, `'nulla' % 2 == 0` devuelve `false`, como el `if` no incluye el enunciado `else` pues no hace nada, en otras palabras asigna a `undefined` a la matriz resultante, y así sucesivamente para cada elemento.

Comment: un usuario me dijo que la funcion aceptaba tres parametros, no me quedo claro el ultimo parametro

Comment: sabrias explicarme porque me devuelve undefined